# regular expression for number in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have number like this

```
90.1103.41
90440036.1112.227
90.1112.228
90.1001.0009
```

How can I validate RegularExpression in c#?

Comment: None of the above are real numbers, what you are trying do ? do you want your string to contain only numbers and `.` ?

Comment: Validate numbers? Are these sample of valid inputs or invalid?

Comment: @Habib, the samples could be considered numbers also if "." is group separator - James123 actually have to explain what he tries to validate with RegEx.

Comment: @James123, agree with Alexei! For example, Are these valid or invalid - `1234`, `123.`, `.567`, `23..45` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\d` character class to match a digit (characters `'0'` - `'9'`).

The `+` to matches at least one occurrence of the previous entity (group/character/etc.).

Use `\.` to match a literal period character (`'.'`).

The `^` and `$` indicate that pattern must match the string from the beginning to the end.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

const string pattern = @"^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$";
Regex.IsMatch("90.11103.41", pattern);       //true
Regex.IsMatch("90440036.1112.227", pattern); //true
Regex.IsMatch("90.1112.228", pattern);       //true
Regex.IsMatch("90.1001.0009", pattern);      //true
```

If your requirement is that there will be at least two groups of numbers, you could use a pattern of:

```
^(\d+\.)+\d+$
```

If your requirement is that there will be at least one group of numbers, you could use:

```
^(\d+\.)*\d+$
```

If your requirement is that some fixed range of numbers of groups is acceptable, you could use

```
^(\d+\.){m,n}\d+$
```

Where `m` and `n` would get replaced with the minimum and maximum number of groups preceding the last group.

Another way to express an exact number of numeric groups like this would be:

```
^(\d+\.){m}\d+$
```

Where `m` is a placeholder for the desired number of groups minus `1`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
string yourNumber = "90440036.1112.227";

Match m = Regex.Match(yourNumber,@"[\d\.]+")

if(m.Success)
{
    //valid
}

else
{
    //invalid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Try

```
^(?:\d\.?)+$
```

and your code:

```
bool foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(inputString, @"^(?:\d\.?)+$");

123.456.789        valid
123...456789       invalid
...123..           invalid
123456             valid
```

explain

> ***`(?:subexpression)`***
>   Defines a noncapturing group.
>
> ***`\d`***
>   Matches any decimal digit.
>
> ***`\.`***
>   Matches `.` character
>
> ***`?`***
>   Matches the previous element zero or one time.
>
> ***`+`***
>   Matches the previous element one or more times.